# Two Laravel projects on same server causing conflict

Tags: php, apache, laravel, server

I have two Laravel 5.1 projects on a same server. Operating on a single project is not giving me any troubles, but if I open the two projects on two browser tabs and alternate between them, I receive

> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Made a research and found out that the server is remembering the first opened project .env file and tries to use it for the project B, which is causing the issue. The question is - how to solve this problem, without changing the server for one of my projects?

Comment: Are you using the same APP_KEY in .env for both projects?

Comment: Make sure that your server configuration is correct and that the two projects are not sharing any files.

Comment: That message should mean a useful error message in the logs. They likely need different cookie names. Change the value of `cookie` in `config/session.php` so they use separate sessions.

Comment: I am using different cookie names for the projects and the APP_KEY is different too.

Comment: Then check the logs for the details of the 500 error.

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this error before in my environments.

This is generally caused by the webserver process running as the same user for both of the projects. As the .env file is loaded for the running user, when you run two projects under the same user, the .env files are loaded for both projects and the variables keep overwriting each other in the user environment.

The solution is to rename the variables in your .env and config files (and everywhere else you use env() function).

```
PROJECT1_APP_KEY=foo
```

and then

```
app_key => env(PROJECT1_APP_KEY, '')
```

in your config.

Comment: Not a proper solution

Comment: I agree with @KeyurMistry that this does sound a bit like a workaround rather than an actual solution. Laravel should, I believe, allow for multiple apps in same server... Does anyone know if this has been brought up to the wonderful people behing Laravel?

Comment: that's not really a solution