# Conflict database when Multiple Laravel Projects on single machine or laravel not reading .env file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, environment-variables, laravel-5.1

I am using xampp on windows 10. I have multiple laravel 5.2 projects on this machine. When I am executing Project 1 it gives me the error that `database_project_1.table_of_project_2` table or view do not exist, but the table `table_of_project_2` is existing in the `database_project_2`. This issue comes rarely.

Below is the **Project 1** .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:ratSluNv930gb3wp1UOabW6Ze3jEJn3ixtTX/wgqYZc=
APP_URL=http://project-1.dev/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_project_1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=j@yshr33r@m
```

Below is the **Project 2** .env file

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:XRgQHfYiKPmHtHZ5UbX38KDlBnl/nyBSt+8qnkOISTg=
APP_URL=http://project-2.dev/

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=database_project_2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=j@yshr33r@m
```

I have tried below commands but with no luck:

1. `php artisan config:clear`
2. `php artisan cache:clear`

Please check the screenshot below: 
[image: Database Confict Error]

Please let me know if any thing is missing.

Here is the `config/database.php` code for both projects.

**Project 1 `config/database.php`**

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_project_1'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'j@yshr33r@m'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
];
```

**Project 2 `config/database.php`**

```
<?php

return [
    'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
    'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
    'connections' => [
        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_project_2'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'j@yshr33r@m'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],

    ],
    'migrations' => 'migrations',
    'redis' => [
        'cluster' => false,
        'default' => [
            'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
            'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', 6379),
            'database' => 0,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Take a look at the code and let me know anything required.

Is it problem with reading `.env` file or conflicting `.env`file of another project?

Comment: What does `config/database.php` look like?

Comment: @Don't Panic : I have added `config/database.php` file for both the projects

Comment: Do you have other Laravel projects as well and it is only these two that have the problem?  Is the problem in both directions or does one of the projects work as expected?

Comment: There are many other laravel projects and they all have same issue

Comment: Have you tried restarting your XAMPP environment? Or your machine altogether?

Comment: Hmm - why is project 2 using `database_project_1`?

Comment: The other thing you could try is php artisan config:cache (https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/configuration#configuration-caching)

Comment: @Don'tPanic: sorry `env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_project_2')` was typing mistake. It was just an example name of db

Comment: but as you mentioned in your answer that caching issue or issue with reading `.env` file

Comment: I have the exact same issue, have set up 2 different projects in my local xampp, First project has opened API and another project is using it, but when API is used 1st project starts to use 2nd project's DB name.

Marked answer is not working for me, both projects config is different

Comment: We are facing the same issue on our end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have specified to use `database_project_1` in Project 2's `config/database.php`:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_project_1'),
```

So if ever `env('DB_DATABASE')` does not return a value , the default of `database_project_1` will be used.  That can happen depending on caching, as described in a few questions here on SO: [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34420761/laravel-5-2-not-reading-env-file), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040967/accesing-laravel-env-variables-in-blade), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39046560/laravel-5-2-envapp-env-does-not-work-in-production).

If it is a caching issue, you can try to fix that by some combination of the following (varies between installs and versions):

```
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
composer dump-autoload
// restart your web server
```

But surely the simplest fix would be to just use the correct default value in your Project 2 `config/database.php`:

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_project_2'),
```

Comment: Do you know why the .env file would not be read in preference to the config/database.php file?

Comment: @kerrin Good question - I added some info.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: sorry `env('DB_DATABASE', 'database_project_2')` was typing mistake. It was just an example name of db. But can be issue with cache or reading `.env` file

Comment: @PankajMakwana did this answer solved your issue?

because it isn't working for me, I had to do a workaround for this i.e define
`protected $table='DB1_Name.TABLE_NAME`

without this, project 1 is using project 2 DB name
@Don'tPanic any idea how can I fix this, I have cleared all caches already

Comment: @PankajJha I would suggest opening a new question with clear details - there was some confusion and typos in the OP's question.  Also, [clearly writing out the question as if explaining it to someone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42161/has-anyone-found-an-answer-to-a-question-using-stack-overflow-without-actually-p) can help! :-)

Comment: @Don'tPanic thanks for the pointer.
finally, my issue was resolved because of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789681/two-laravel-projects-on-same-server-causing-conflict)

I updated my project 1 env file `DB_DATABASE` to `DB_DATABASE1` and updated same in its config file.

Answer (score 1):

On production we should use `cache` for config and should not use `env('xxx')` at runtime.
If you like to use `env` function, I suggest that use different name for each project

```
DB_DATABASE_PROJECT1=pro1
DB_USERNAME_PROJECT1=user1
DB_PASSWORD_PROJECT1=xxx
```

and

```
'database' => env('DB_DATABASE_PROJECT1', 'project_1'),
...
```

cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan config:cache
php artisan route:cache
```